# Set authentication for solr, when deployed as war in tomcat

Tags: solr

We have solr 6.4.2 currently deployed as war in tomcat. It doesn't have authentication now. I want to setup the authentication for solr. The process specified in below page is not working, when it deployed as war in tomcat.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html#AuthenticationandAuthorizationPlugins-EnablePluginswithsecurity.json

Did anyone did this before? If so, please guide me.

Comment: You're probably have to [go with Tomcat's authentication instead](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

Comment: @MatsLindh, Did the Solr basic authorization won't work, if it's deployed as war in tomcat? Is there any reason why it won't work?

Comment: No idea. Tomcat is not supported from the Solr side of things since 4.x, so you're on your own when deciding to use an alternative container. But be aware - using security.json outside of a cloud/cluster context was added in 6.5.